# How to load helper from model in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

I want to load some helper in a model. How to do this? Tried to use:

```
${get_parent_class($this)}->load->helper ('text');
```

But still getting an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$this->load->helper('helpername')
```

Comment: the $this refers to the application instance, which can't be reliably accessed from within a model.  MWM has it right, by assigning (byref) an instance of the CI application and accessing it using $CI->load->helper('foo').

Comment: Helpers are not available unless you have the CI object loaded. See mwm's answer.

Answer (score 41):

GSto answered `$this->load->helper('helpername')` but if you are in a model's method, `$this` simply refers to that model's (class) instance and not to CI global. That won't work!

Instead you need to load the CI global and then load the helper:

```
// PHP 4
// $ci =& get_instance();
// PHP 5    
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('text');
```

Comment: That's correct, but it is recommended to assign by reference like so: $ci =& get_instance(); to make sure that you are using the original CodeIgniter object instead of copying it. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html (bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

You are not need to load helper in a model.Just load helper in a controller and use function in a model as well as we normally use helper function in a controller

Comment: You should make this more clear by using example code

Comment: Sorry, but that's not quite correct. Sometimes helpers are required in model methods for sanitization etc.

Answer (score -2):

I think CI doesnt check for helper duplication ... CI herlpers are procedural files , you might include ur helper twice if ur controller has the same helper loaded as ur model (that is loaded in that controller).  Maybe do a library instead...

I can see i get negative votes w/o any comments ... by checking loader class from core CI u can see helpers method isnt checking if the helper has been loaded before (it isn't included in is_loaded() array like most classes that are loaded through load factory class) ... I dont recommend anyway to load helpers in both models and controllers ... for ex i made a helper for output encoding that i use in controllers (before i pass data to the view) . It would be very bad if i change the view state twice ...